# Multiplayer in a game. How to design it object wise?

Tags: java, oop, multiplayer

I'm working on a simple game and I was thinking of adding multiplayer feature but I'm a bit stuck. I'm not sure what approach should I take, keeping in mind good programming practices.

I have a `Player` object which is created for each player but then I have many other classes that would have to be able to access them. The thing is, if I initialise them in, let's say my `main` method, then I can't relate to different instances of player class from other classes. The only solution to my problem that comes to my mind is using some form of global objects but afaik using anything globally in apps is usually not a good practice. Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could try to ask on [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) if you do not receive the wanted answer here. Just a tip. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I am not sure what the context is, here is my suggestion according to my perception of the problem.

A common practice in games is to have a more abstract object to manage the game. Within this 'Game'-object you can manage the addition/removal of players. To fix your problem of being unable to reach the other players from one player, you provide the players with the game-object as an attribute. Using the Game-attribute a player can access the other players and any other data which is relevant meta-data to the game (such as the rules of the game).

Comment: You are suggesting creating a Game object on which Player would be dependent on. Is my understanding correct? Wouldn't I still have a problem if I would want to access initialised Game object with some other class? A short code sample would be nice.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. And yes you could of course still have the same problem if you want to access the players from an unrelated class. However that would be a bad practice, as the objects of relevance to the game should be connected (or dependent) of each other. Having a class completely unrelated to the Game, while still trying to access it would be a paradox in the OOP-sense.